# How to check if there is already an image in dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have the following code:

**CODE JS:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
    url             : "<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . '/profile/ajax/dzupload'; ?>",
    paramName       : 'profilepicture',
    acceptedFiles   : "image/*",
    maxFiles        : 1,
    addRemoveLinks  : true,
    init            : function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {

            $('#profilePicture').attr("value", responseText.filename);
            console.log(responseText);
        });

        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
            this.removeFile(file);
            alert("You are not allowed to chose more than 1 file!");
        });

        this.on("removedfile", function (file){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo $this->serverUrl() . '/profile/ajax/dzdelete' ?>',
                data: {
                    area    : 'company-profile',
                    name    : $('#profilePicture').attr('value')
                },
                success: function(result){
                    $('#profilePicture').attr("value", '')
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
        });
    }
});

      var fileName = $('#profilePicture').val();
      var mockFile = { name: fileName, size: 12345 };
      myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
      myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "<?php echo $this->serverUrl().'/public/profile/'.'usr'.$practitionerInfo->user_id.'/picture/'.$practitionerInfo->profilepicture ?>");
```

I would like to check if there is already loaded an image... if not there then lets you add another image until I delete the previous

I tried the following code but it does not work

```
if(!myDropzone.file.length()){
    //allow to upload file
}else{
   alert("please remove existing file");
}
```

How can I do this? I hope I was able to explain well.

**EDIT:**

If you add this code 0 but the picture is added receive default and should be one, right?

```
console.log(myDropzone.files.length) //return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it. Because `myDropzone.files` is an array, `myDropzone.files.length` will tell you if you have any selected files.

```
if (!myDropzone.files || !myDropzone.files.length) {
  // allow to upload file
} else {
  alert("please remove existing file");
}
```

I included a `!myDropzone.files` check because I'm not 100% sure when this property is initialized, so it may be undefined when you're trying to check its length.

Comment: @D.Cristi the `files` array only contains the files that are in the Dropzone control. If you want to prevent a user from uploading a second profile picture, you could disable uploads in your success handler or replace the existing profile picture with the new one.